# MySql/Oracle Remove gaps of numeric column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, gaps-in-data

First of all, I need a solution for **Oracle** and **MySQL**.

I Have a folder table :

```
id | name | parent_id | position
_________________________________
1  | root | null      | 1
2  | a    | 1         | 1
3  | b    | 1         | 2
4  | b1   | 3         | 1
5  | b2   | 3         | 2
6  | c    | 1         | 3
7  | d    | 1         | 4
8  | e    | 1         | 5
```

given the tree :

```
root
  |_ a
  |_ b
  |  |_b1
  |  |_b2
  |_c
  |_d
  |_e
```

The column `position` has a `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` constraint.

**Problem :**
Sometimes i have to delete some folders in a single query (ex : delete folder 'a', 'b1', 'd'). When doing this i have gaps in folders position :

```
id | name | parent_id | position
_________________________________
1  | root | null      | 1
3  | b    | 1         | 2
5  | b2   | 3         | 2
6  | c    | 1         | 3
8  | e    | 1         | 5
```

So I need to update the table in single request for updating the position column and in a specific order (to prevent the `UNIQUE` constraint) to obtain the result :

```
id | name | parent_id | position
_________________________________
1  | root | null      | 1
3  | b    | 1         | 2
5  | b2   | 3         | 1
6  | c    | 1         | 2
8  | e    | 1         | 3
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks

Comment: `Remove gaps` mean update the table?

Comment: yes, i need to update the table but i search to do this in one request

Comment: And the same SQL statement has to work with both MySQL and Oracle? Could be tricky...

Comment: @Yoplaboom please choose only one rdbms in yours tags, Oracle or MySql. My solution is for Oracle

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ok, i will remember for it  but i used oracle and mysql tags because i need to do this with both of them :).

Comment: Then you should explain that as part of your question. For your reference please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: But why do you want to renumber? What kind of data has that need?

Comment: this column is position folders column, so when i delete multiple folders, i need to update all folders position. I will edit my topic to be more carefully in the afternoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem :

**Oracle**

```
    UPDATE folders t 
    SET position = ( select count(*)
    FROM folders f1 INNER JOIN folders f2 on ( f1.parent_id = f2.parent_id   and f1.position >= f2.position )
    WHERE f1.id = t.id AND t.parent_id = f1.parent_id
    GROUP BY f1.id, f1.position );
```

**MySQL**

```
    UPDATE folders f
    INNER JOIN ( select f1.id, f1.parent_id, count(*) as newPos
    FROM folders f1 INNER JOIN folders f2 on ( f1.parent_id = f2.parent_id and f1.position >= f2.position)
    GROUP BY f1.parent_id, f1.position) t on ( t.id = f.id and t.parent_id = f.parent_id)
    SET f.position = t.newPos
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
MERGE
INTO    YourTable t1
USING   (
        SELECT pk_id, gap_ID, row_num() over (order by gap_id) as newGap
        FROM YourTable t2
        ) as sub
ON      (t1.pk_id = t2.pk_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     gap_ID = newGap;
```

Comment: You could also use `(order by pk_id)`

Comment: Not sure if ON should be `(t1.pk_id = sub.pk_id)` but i guess you can play with the alias :)